# Do the principal parts of the Laurent expansion at the poles of a meromorphic function determine the function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{P}^1$, then the answer to the question in the title is no. More specifically, suppose we know that $f$ has poles precisely at $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n \in \mathbb{P}^1$ and that the principal part of the Laurent expansion at $z=a_i$ is $\sum_{m=1}^{e_i} x^{m}_i (z-a_i)^{-m}$, then this information only determines $f(z)$ up to adding a scalar.

> Then, what is wrong with the following argument?

Let $u \in\mathbb{P}^1$ be a value at which $f(z)$ is holomorphic. Using the Cauchy integral formula, where $\gamma$ is a small clockwise loop around $z=u$ we know that
$$f(u) = \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-u} dz $$
Now using the residue theorem, we can evaluate the integral around this loop by summing up the residues on the "outside":
$$f(u) = \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-u} dz = - \sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{res}_{z=a_i} \frac{f(z)}{z-u}.$$
Next we aim to calculate these residues. We do this by noting the Taylor series of $(z-u)^{-1}$ at $z=a_i$ is
$$\frac{1}{z-u} = -\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(u-a_i)^{m+1}} (z-a_i)^m$$
and the Laurent series of $f(z)$ is given as 
$$f(z) = \sum_{m=1}^{e_i} x^{m}_i (z-a_i)^{-m} + \text{Taylor part of the series}.$$
To calculate the residue we can take the product of the series to see that
$$\mathrm{res}_{z=a_i} \frac{f(z)}{z-u} = -\sum_{m=1}^{e_i} \frac{x^{m}_i}{(u-a_i)^m},$$
and finally putting this all together we see that 
$$f(u) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{m=1}^{e_i} \frac{x^m_i}{(u-a_i)^m}$$.